# LaTeX - I cannot write under the 2nd figure. How can I write?

Tags: floats, two-column, subcaption

As you can see below, I used subfigure and the articles I wrote under the 2nd figure shifted under the figure 1. How can i fix this. In this way, I have to put 20 figures and write under them.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please do not show code as image, we simply can not copy and test it on our own computers ...

Comment: note that the only purpose of the `figure` environment is to specify that the figure may be moved.  (the `\break` and `\hfill\break` you have before and after the figure do nothing useful in that position just forcing spurious extra white lines in the paragraph.

Comment: Off-topic: In a two-column document, I believe it's more natural to express the widths of the `subfigure` environments as a fraction of `\columnwidth` rather than as a fraction of `\textwidth`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks very much like the two 4-line explanatory paragraphs are supposed to serve as legends to their respective figure environments. Hence, they should never get separated from the other parts of the `figure` environments, right?  To achieve this goal, simply make each legend a part of its respective environment. Use either `\small` or `\footnotesize` to change the legends' font size. This will help readers distinguish between "regular" text and legend material.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption,lipsum,siunitx}
% Place subcaptions close to their respective graphs:
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0.2\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5] % filler text

\begin{figure}[t!] % first 'figure'
\begin{subfigure}{1\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.75\columnwidth]{fig1a}
\caption{Cross-section plot of FT8}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{1\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.75\columnwidth]{fig1b}
\caption{Cross-section plot of FT9}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{1\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.75\columnwidth]{fig1c}
\caption{The values of the shell file used for production}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Results graphics and production file}

\medskip\small % or '\footnotesize'
% now insert legend:
The FT8 and FT9 values in Figures a and b were increased by 
\SI{0.5}{TeV} from \SI{-5.0}{TeV} to \SI{5.0}{TeV}, and the
production was repeated by changing the ebeam 1 and 2 values
to 7000, 16500, and 50000 within both FT values.
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[p!] % second 'figure'
\begin{subfigure}{1\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.75\columnwidth]{fig2a}
\caption{Cross-section plot of FT0}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{1\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.75\columnwidth]{fig2b}
\caption{Cross-section plot of FT1}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{1\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.75\columnwidth]{fig2c}
\caption{Cross-section plot of FT2}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{1\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.75\columnwidth]{fig2d}
\caption{The values of the shell file used for production}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Results graphics and production file}

\medskip\small % or '\footnotesize'
% insert the appropriate legend
The FT0, FT1, and FT2 values in Figures a, b, and c were increased by 
\SI{0.5}{TeV} from \SI{-5.0}{TeV} to \SI{5.0}{TeV}, and the
production was repeated by changing the ebeam 1 and 2 values
to 7000, 16500, and 50000 within all three FT values.
\end{figure}

\lipsum[6-20] % more filler text

\end{document}
```